# Find parameter for $y = a - \sqrt{b-x} \cdot c$; (Parameter known but not the way to determine them)

Tags: linear-algebra

I have the function of the form
$y = a - \sqrt{b-x} \cdot c$
and want to determine the parameter $a,b,c.$ The function should go through the points $(0,0)$, $(1.7,1.7)$ and $(0.5,0.272)$. From trial & error using plots, I know that the parameters are roguhly $a = 1.7, b = 1.7, c = 1.304.$

However, its bugging me that I don't find the analytic solution for it.

I started to build a linear equation system ($Ax=b$) to solve it e.g. via (pseudo)inverse or gaussian elemination, but then failed to set up $A$ when it comes to the parameters b and c. Can anybody explain me the way to solve this please?
Thanks for any hints or solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We rearrange and square, and we get the equation:$$bc^2-c^2x_i=a^2-2ay_i+y_i^2\tag1$$

for $i=1,2,3.$

We can solve for $A=bc^2,B=c^2,C=a,D=a^2.$

You get a set of three linear equations:

$$A-x_iB+(2y_i)C-D=y_i^2\quad i=1,2,3\tag{2}$$

This should result in a line, for most sets of points $(x_i,y_i).$ That is, there is a parameterized formula:

$$(A,B,C,D)=(A_0+tA_1,B_0+tB_1,C_0+tC_1,D_0+tD_1)$$

---

Solving for $B,C$ in (2) is easy - we’ll see they are fixed, so $B_1,C_1=0.$ subtracting, you get:

$$(x_2-x_1)B+2(y_1-y_2)C=y_1^2-y_2^2\\
(x_3-x_2)B+2(y_2-y_3)C=y_2^2-y_3^2$$

And you solve for $B,C.$ There will be one solution, unless the three points $(x_i,y_i)$ are colinear.

If $c^2=B<0,$ there will not be any solution.

Once you’ve solved for $C,$ we get $D=C^2.$

And then we can solve for $A.$

There might be no solution for $A,$ but there usually will be one.

At this point, we solve for $$a=C,b=A/B,c=\pm\sqrt{B}.$$

If $B=0,A\neq 0,$ there is no solutions.

If $A=0,B=0,$ then $c=0,$ and $b$ is irrelevant.

You’ll still need to check for the two values of $c=\pm\sqrt B,$ since the first equation was gotten by squaring. It’s possible that the $(x_i,y_i)$ will not work with the same sign for $c.$

In particular, if $c$ is positive, then all $y_i<a$ and if $c$ is negative, all $y_i>a.$

---

You’re case:

$$1.7B-3.4C=-1.7^2\\-1.2B+2.856C=1.7^2-0.272^2$$

WolframAlpha gives me $B= 1.70358,C= {1.70179}.$

Then $D\approx  2.89609.$ Since $(0,0)$ was a point, then $A=D.$

$$a=1.70179,b=1.7,c=1.305212.$$

$c$ is positive because all $y_i<a.$